# Get distinct attribute from database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables, one called `"products"` and another `"product_brands"`.

A product has one brand, and a brand can belong to many products.

I have:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function type() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductTypes');
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductBrands', 'id', 'brand_id');
    }

    public function image() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductImages');
    }

    public function toArray() {

        $ar = $this->attributes;

        $ar['type'] = $this->type;
        $ar['brand'] = $this->brand;

        return $ar;
    }

    public function getBrandAttribute() {
        $brand = $this->brand()->first();
        return (isset($brand->brand) ? $brand->brand : '');
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController {

    public function index($type_id) {
        $Product = new Product;
        $products = $Product->where('type_id', $type_id)->get();
        return View::make('products.products', array('products' => $products));
    }

}
```

**Ideally I would like the column from `"product_brands"` to be in the same array as the columns from `"products"`**, hence why I am trying that stuff with `toArray()` and `getBrandAttribute()` but it isn't working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the `getBrandAttribute` accessor collides with the `brand` relationship. Try this instead:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function type() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductTypes');
    }

    public function productBrand() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductBrands', 'id', 'brand_id');
    }

    public function image() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductImages');
    }

    public function getBrandAttribute() {
        $brand = $this->productBrand()->first();
        return (isset($brand->brand) ? $brand->brand : '');
    }

    protected $appends = array('brand'); // this makes Laravel include the property in toArray

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your accessor to other name:

```
public function getSpecBrandAttribute() {
    $brand = $this->brand()->first();
    return (isset($brand->brand) ? $brand->brand : '');
}
```

and in `toArray` you should then use:

```
public function toArray() {

    $ar = $this->attributes;

    $ar['type'] = $this->type;
    $ar['brand'] = $this->spec_brand;

    return $ar;
}
```

That's because you shouldn't create fields with the same name as relationship name.

In addition as it's one to many relationship, probably for `brand()` you should use `belongsTo` and not `hasOne`